# htaccess - Make a RewriteCond gobal

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements, global

Is it possible to make 1 or more `RewriteCond` gobal in `htaccess` to avoid repeating

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

at the beginning of every RewriteRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes repetition can be avoided by having your conditions like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  =POST [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Which means **skip rest of the rules** if any of these conditions are met:

1. If request is for `POST` method OR
2. If request is for a valid file OR
3. If request is for a valid directory

**PS:** Make sure to place this rule on top of other rules you want to skip.

Comment: Nice one! you have just made my htaccess file 15% lighter

Comment: Your welcome. Yes this surely reduces lot of those redundant lines.

Comment: wait...error 404 on POST request could you please double check?

Comment: POST requests will be skipped from further rewrites. You can replace `=POST` by `^POST$`

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST$  also produce a 404 error I don't see why...

Comment: I retested `=POST` and it worked pretty well on my host.

Comment: I know. If I post to search.php using http://localhost/search.php it is working but not with http://localhost/search How can I keep it the 2nd way?

Comment: I think it could be due to rule above it. If you place `=POST` rule on top it will skip all POST requests.

Comment: `Options +MultiViews` is actually pretty nasty for rewrite so do test your other rules after enabling it.